# VS Code not finding pytest tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest, pytest-django

I have PyTest setup in vs-code but none of the tests are being found even though running pytest from the command line works fine.

(I'm developing a Django app on Win10 using MiniConda and a Python 3.6.6 virtual env. VS Code is fully updated and I have the Python and Debugger for Chrome extensions installed)

Pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = callsign.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

vs-code workspace settings:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\callsign\\python.exe",
        "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": false,
        "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
        "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
        "python.unitTest.pyTestArgs": ["--rootdir=.\\callsign", "--verbose"]
    }
}
```

Finally, the output from the Python Test Log inside VS code:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
Django settings: callsign.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: c:\Users\benhe\Projects\CallsignCopilot\callsign, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.4.5
collected 23 items
<Package c:\Users\benhe\Projects\CallsignCopilot\callsign\transcription>
  <Module test_utils.py>
    <Function test_n_digits>
    <Function test_n_alpha>
    <Function test_n_hex>
    <Function test_n_digits_in_range>
    <Function test_v1_audiofilename>
    <Function test_v2_audiofilename>
    <Function test_v1_bad_int_filename>
    <Function test_v1_bad_non_int_filename>
    <Function test_bad_format>
    <Function test_no_format>
    <Function test_too_many_segments>
    <Function test_too_few_segments>
    <Function test_good_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_year_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_month_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_day_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_date_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_short_serial_v2_filename>
    <Function test_bad_long_serial_v2_filename>
    <Function test_good_v3_filename>
    <Function test_good_lowercase_block_v3_filename>
    <Function test_bad_non_alpha_block_v3_filename>
    <Function test_real_filenames>

======================== no tests ran in 1.12 seconds =========================
```

Am I missing any steps to get vs-code to find the tests?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If anyone comes across this post-2020, [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8184) in the `vscode-python` repo saved my life. Basically, just do the following:

1. Uninstall the `Python` extension
2. Delete the file that contains the extension from your `~/.vscode` folder (mine looked like `ms-python.python-[YEAR].[MONTH].[VERSION]`)
3. Reinstall the extension

Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Peter Did you reload the VSCode window after uninstalling/deleting and again after reinstalling?

Comment: Still worked for me in 2022!

Comment: Yes...Worked for me too in 2022

Comment: I can't believe this works! wtf, thank you

Comment: Dec 23 still the answer

Answer (score 7):

My Python plugin and Test Explorer works just fine.

In my case naming the class without `test_.py` was the issue. In other words, naming the test file without it starting with `"test_"`, not `"tests_"`, makes it so the explorer does not see the issue. Ex: `test_.py` works but `tests_.py`, `12345abcde.py` don't work.

Comment: Ugh, finally, something that worked. I usually `test_`, but had just fat fingered it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

VScode needs to specify python configure:

1. Open Command Palette by `Ctrl` + `shift` + `p` OR `command` + `shift` + `p` for mac users.
2. and write this `>python: configure tests` And follow the program directions

Note: You may need (Mostly you will not need) to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988898/15107127) first before following the previous steps

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to check, if vscode fails to discover the tests, is to make sure it doesn't do so because of the [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1/) module being enabled. In my case the test cases were being discovered correctly but the discovery eventually kept failing due to low test coverage, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62197127/8741356). So first, make sure that the tests could actually be collected by `pytest` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57963397/8741356):

```
pytest --collect-only
```

and then make sure you're not forcing coverage check (e.g. in `setup.cfg`) with e.g.

```
addopts= --cov <path> -ra
```

Comment: You sir, saved me lots of hours! Thanks!

Comment: I had a syntax error - "expected indentation" or similar (I had a dangling if `__name__ == "__main__":` statement). The error didn't seem to show up until I ran `pytest --collect-only` (though maybe it would have if I just did `pytest` instead of clicking on the VS Code buttons). Thank you!

Comment: For me it was mypy set in pytest.ini killing the test discovery. Unfortunately there is no option to disable mypy (https://github.com/realpython/pytest-mypy/issues/138) and I had to use https://github.com/jaraco/pytest-enabler

Answer (score 5):

In September 2021, I was able to get VS code to find the test directory again by downgrading the VS Code Python extension from version 2021.9.1191016588 to version v2021.8.1159798656. To downgrade, right-click the extension and click "Install another version..."

Comment: This worked for me on the latest version of visual studio.

Comment: Worked for me too, was on now-latest v2021.10.1336267007.  Thanks!  (No idea what the cause is, can't see any error logged anywhere with that newer extension version, just acts as if the project has no tests while `pytest` command line discovers and runs the tests just fine.)

Comment: This works for me today 06/02/2023. I reinstalled the Python extension to a version of 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: I downgraded to Pytest 4.0.1 after reading [issue 3911](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3911) and Test Discovery now works.

---

Me too. When I blow away `.pytest_cache` and rerun `Python: Discover Unit Tests`, I see that the freshly generated `.pytest_cache/v/cache/nodeids` contains all the tests, but I still get the dialog complaining about `No tests discovered`.

- Python 3.7.2
- macOS 10.13.6
- VS Code 1.30.2
- Python Extension 2018.12.1
- Pytest 4.1.0

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "venv3/bin/python"
}
```

Tests are in a top-level subdirectory called `test`. Running `pytest` manually works.

Comment: Do the tests show up in the Test Explorer for you after rerunning Python: Discover Tests? I still don't see anything after downgrading.

Comment: Update for 9th of october: you should be using:

```json

  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,

```

Answer (score 3):

The following steps worked for me (assuming latest PyTest installed in Visual Studio Code):

1. Make sure there are no errors (bottom left of Visual Studio Code)
   [image]
2. In Visual Studio Code from File menu choose: **File > Close Folder** (i.e. close current project folder) and close Visual Studio Code.
3. Re-open Visual Studio Code and choose: **File > Open Folder** (re-open the folder that contains your project/test files).
4. Choose **Testing** and should have visibility of tests from here ...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An obvious thing that caught me...

The test folder hierarchy needs `__init__.py` files in each folder.

I refactored my tests introducing an extra folder layer and forgot to add `__init__.py` files.
Command line didn't complain but vscode showed no tests found

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I had a syntax error in a source file which caused the pytest discovery to fail. Also, note that you get the traceback from `Output` (tab) -> `Python` (dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

If everything here fails and you checked all the basic configurations, try specifying the path to your test folder in your workspace's `settings.ini` file like so. The three configurations below it are from the majority of other solutions.

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/tests"
],
"python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
"python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

> "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true

on .vscode to false and reload VScode, and them before trying to run the tests selected the proper python interpreted by using command pallete on python: select interpreter, and it worked properly.

So was pretty much wrong interpreted selected at VScode at the time I tried to run the tests on the extension.

Also, I'm using a conda environment, which may be relevant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).