# VSCode pytest test discovery fails

Tags: python, pytest, visual-studio-code

Pytest test discovery is failing. The UI states:

`Test discovery error, please check the configuration settings for the tests`

The output window states:

```
Test Discovery failed: 
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikep\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py", line 16, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikep\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py", line 90, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikep\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest.py", line 43, in discover
    raise Exception('pytest discovery failed (exit code {})'.format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 3)
```

Here are my settings:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.testing.pyTestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pyTestEnabled": true
}
```

I can run pytest from the command line successfully FWIW.

Comment: How are you running pytest from the command-line? Are you using pytest from your virtual environment with the same args as specified in your settings.json?

Comment: From the command line I'm just doing `pytest tests` from within the same virtual env that VS Code is using.

Comment: yea I also run pytest from the terminal within VSCode and than it was discovered, so that I could run it from the GUI afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue by upgrading pytest to the latest version: 4.4.1 with "pip install --upgrade pytest". I was apparently running an old version 3.4.2

Comment: A better answer would: 1. Tell why the older version was causing the problem, specifically. 2. Tell how the new version solved the problem. Randomly upgrading is an obvious solution, and most don't need to go to stackoverflow to learn this.

Answer (score 177):

I spent ages trying to decipher this unhelpful error after creating a test that had import errors.   Verify that your test suite can actually be executed before doing any deeper troubleshooting.

`pytest --collect-only` is your friend.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables sth like `================================================ 76 tests collected in 0.16s =================================================`

Comment: @autumn But it is just discovering and showing on command line I need to see in vs code test tab?

Comment: and what to do if that fails?

Comment: It worked for me: It showed the error message from the test which was throwing the error. It doesn't make sense to me that collecting the test already runs it. If I comment the failed code, the "error discovering pytest tests" is gone.

Comment: This was super helpful! I had an errant uncommented line that was causing the test discovery to fail, and this command highlighted that error immediately.

Comment: I had a circular import in my code and was facing this issue. Using `pytest --collect-only` helped me get rid of the circular import and fix this issue.

Answer (score 66):

This is not a complete answer as I do not know why this is happening and may not relate to your problem, depending how you have your tests structured.

I resolved this issue by putting an `__init__.py` file in my tests folder

E.G.:

```
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───app
│       myapp.py
│
└───tests
        test_myapp.py
        __init__.py
```

this was working a few days ago without this but the python extension was recently updated.  I am not sure if this is the intended behavior or a side effect of how discoveries are now being made

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
`Use Python code for discovery of tests when using pytest. (#4795)`

Comment: I have `__init__.py` in my `tests` dir.

Comment: @devlife does helgso solution apply to you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55856949/9532163) I can confirm when I downgraded I get the same issue with exit code 3.

Comment: If you have submodules inside your `tests` folder, add the `__init__` file in those subfolders too

Comment: My solution was to do the opposite: *remove the `__init__.py`*. Not sure why that fixes it, or why it became broken in the first place. I'm sure that a while back I had to add it instead.

Answer (score 17):

### tldr (checklist)

1. Disable test `coverage` module
2. Set `--rootdir` parameter in `"python.testing.pytestArgs"`
3. Ensure the right VSCode's interpreter is set
4. See if your tests are discoverable (i.e. without errors) with `pytest --collect-only`

### Disable test `coverage` module

In my case the problem with vscode being unable to discover tests was the [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1/) module being enabled in the `setup.cfg` (alternatively this could be a `pytest.ini`), i.e.

```
addopts= --cov <path> -ra
```

which caused the test discovery to fail due to low coverage. The solution was to remove that line from the config file.

Also, as suggested in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_enable-a-test-framework):

> You can also configure testing manually **by setting one and only one** of the following settings to true: `python.testing.unittestEnabled`, `python.testing.pytestEnabled`, and `python.testing.nosetestsEnabled`.

In `settings.json` you can also disable coverage using `--no-cov` flag:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": ["--no-cov"],
```

### Set `--rootdir` parameter in `"python.testing.pytestArgs"`

Slightly related - in case of more complex projects it might be also necessary to change the `rootdir` parameter (inside your `settings.json`) when running tests with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) (in case of `ModuleNotFoundError`):

```
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--rootdir","${workspaceFolder}/<path-to-directory-with-tests>"
    ],
```

### Ensure the right VSCode's interpreter is set

It could be that VSCode is using a different Python interpreter than your terminal. VSCode's interpreter might not have the right dependencies installed which causes the test discovery to fail.

solution:

```
Open Command Palette (Cmd + Shift + P) -> "Select interpreter"
```

Comment: I had spent more than few weeks trying to figure out pytest discovery failure. Explicitly setting `rootdir` fixed the problem finally. Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 16):

I just thought I would add my answer here as this might well affect someone who uses a `.env` file for their project's environment settings since it is such a common configuration for 12 factor apps.

My example assumes that you're using `pipenv` for your virtual environment management and that you have a `.env` file at the project's root directory.

My vscode workspace settings json file looks like below. The crucial line for me here was `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",`

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": ".venv/bin/pylint",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
    ],
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--line-length",
        "100"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestPath": ".venv/bin/pytest",
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--no-cov"
    ],
}
```

I hope this saves someone the time I spent figuring this out.

Comment: Thanks, the env file setting worked in my case, too. I required either CLI options or alternatively environment variables to set critical values for my tests. And specifying them in the tox.ini etc. was not possible as they were private in nature.

Comment: For me it was ```"python.testing.pytestPath": "{$workspaceFolder}\\Lib\\pytest",```

Comment: This worked for me, I specifically forgot the `--no-cov` when I added that it work immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Seems like a bug in the latest version of VS Code Python extension. I had the same issue, then I downgraded the Python extension to **2019.3.6558** and then it works again. So we should go to our VS Code extensions list, select the Python extension and "Install another version..." from the setting of that extension.

I hope this works for you too.

Comment: Many thanks ! downgrading from 2020.1.58038 to 2019.3.6558, my tests are discovered now. Before I had ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.conftest'

Answer (score 5):

Before begin the tests discovery, check that `python.testing.cwd` points correctly to your tests dir and your `python.testing.pytestEnabled` is set to `true`.

Once those requirements are set correctly, run tests discovery and its output (see *OUTPUT* window). You should see something like this:

```
python $HOME/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-$VERSION/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir $ROOT_DIR_OF_YOUR_PROJECT -s --cache-clear
Test Discovery failed: 
Error: ============================= test session starts ==============================
<SETTINGS RELATED TO YOUR MACHINE, PYTHON VERSION, PYTEST VERSION,...>
collected N items / M errors
...
```

It's important to highlight here the last line: `collected N items / M errors`. The following lines will contain info about the tests discovered by `pytest`. So your tests **are discoverable** but there are errors related to their correct execution.

The following lines will contain the errors which in **most of the cases will be related to an incorrect import**.

Check that all your dependencies have been downloaded previously. If you are working with specific versions of dependencies (on the`requirements.txt` file you have something like `your_package == X.Y.Z`) be sure that it's the right version that you need to.

Comment: `python.testing.cwd`  wasn't in my configuration, this was that helpd!

Answer (score 4):

If you are having trouble with `pytest` I was struggling with the discovery test part.

Reading some [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11513) [(other)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6594) in vscode I found a workaround using `the test-adapter` extension

[market_place_link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter)

The extention works like a charm. (and solve my discovery problem)

Answer (score 4):

Test files need to be named `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` for pytest collection to work.

Then run `pytest --collect-only` at the command line to make sure all of the tests are found.  Then magically, the flask icon in VSCode suddenly shows the test files and their tests.

As a noob, I was putting my unit tests *inside* the module files, since I was following the pattern of `unittest`, and then running `pytest *.py`. That doesn't work with pytest, and I didn't find a command line argument override the naming convention.

Answer (score 3):

I've had headaches with this as well. Got it running now, and I thought I'd share the steps I undertook to get it running.

(Windows 10, Python 3.11, VS Code 1.75.1, pytest 7.2.1)

I don't understand all the steps, and don't know if they are all necessary, but at least it worked.

My project structure is like this:

```
src
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───app
│       __init__.py
│       myapp.py
│
└───tests
        __init__.py
        conftest.py
        test_myapp.py
```

The main folder that I use/open in VS Code is `src`. Anything above that (docs, venv-related  etc.) is not accessible within VS Code with this layout.

Steps:

1. Uninstall and reinstall Python extension in VS Code, but this might not be necessary.
2. Delete all these folders in and under `src` (recursively), if they exist: `.pytest_cache` and `__pycache__` (although the latter might not be necessary).
3. Put empty `__init__.py` files in the folders as depicted in the project structure above.
4. `src/.vscode/settings.json` contains this:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

5. In the testcase files (including `conftest.py`) I incude the following, ***before*** importing my app (e.g. `import app` or `from app import ...` etc.):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

main_folder = Path(__file__).parent.parent
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder))
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder / 'app'))
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder / 'tests'))
os.chdir(main_folder / 'app')

import app
```

This made the tests discoverable and work correctly inside VS Code.

To run the tests on a standalone basis, I include this at the end of each test file:

```
@report_execution_time
def main_test():

    os.system('python -m pytest ..')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main_test()
```

I use the `main_test` function, rather than putting its "body" under
`if __name__ == "__main__":`, so that I can use a decorator on it, in this case to report execution time.

I hope this may help someone or anyone.

Comment: Adding an `__init__.py` to the tests directory did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the vscode python extension problem.
I switched the test platform from pytest and switched to it back again, and the tests got discovered.
It seems that when testing is universally enabled for all python projects and it  fails to discover tests at the beginning, it fails forever!

Answer (score 2):

***2021-12-22***

Please find below the settings I used to get pytest working in VsCode after much frustration.  I found many helpful pieces of advice here and elsewhere on the internet, but none were complete enough to spare me a bit of cursing.  I hope the following  will help someone out.  This setup allows me to run testing visually from the test explorer extension and also from the integrated terminal.  I am using a src format in my workspace and Conda for environment management.  The settings related to the terminal setup keep me from having to manually enable my Conda environment or set the python path.  Possibly people who have been using VSCODE for more than two days could add something nice to make this better and/or more complete.

**##### Vscode info:**

Version: 1.63.2 (Universal)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:37:28.172Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.6.0

**##### Testing Extension:**

Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code
extension installed, v. 0.7.0

**##### Pytest version**

pytest 6.2.5

**##### Directory Structure:**

```
     workspace
       .env
       ./src
            __init__.py
            code1.py
            code2.py
       ./tests
            __init__.py
            test_code1.py
            test_code2.py
```

**##### .env file (in root, but see the "python.envFile" setting in settings.json)**

PYTHONPATH=src

**#####. settings.json**

```
    {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
        "editor.fontFamily": " monospace, Menlo, Monaco, Courier New",
        "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.cwd": ".",
        "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true,
        "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": 
        "~/anaconda3/envs/mycurrentenv/bin/python",
        "pythonTestExplorer.testFramework": "pytest",
        "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
        "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
           "tests"
        ],
        "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
        "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
        "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
          }
    }
```

Comment: tried to do this but it still fails. is the settings.json for workspace or user?

Answer (score 1):

I searched in the settings for "python" and found this:

[image]

Switching to `pytest` automatically detect my tests:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is so frustrating..
In my case the error fixed by modifying the `python.pythonPath` parameter in `settings.json` (found inside `.vscode` folder under project root directory), to the path which I obtained using `which python` in terminal (e.g. `/usr/local/var/pyenv/shims/python`)

I use pyenv with python3.9, and my error said previously:

> Error: Process returned an error: /Users/"user-name"/.pyenv/shims/python:
> line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.23/libexec/pyenv: No such file or
> directory
>
> at ChildProcess.
> (/Users/"user-name"/.vscode/extensions/littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter-0.6.8/out/src/processRunner.js:35:36)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)    at ChildProcess.emit
> (events.js:315:20)    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:286:5)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to make sure that I was using the right interpreter where the libraries where installed (I used a virtual environment) but the interpreter was pointing to the globally installed python. After changing the interpreter to that of the virtual environment, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several causes for this.

The simple answer is, it is not perfect. Furthermore, *Python is not native to VS Code*; Python extensions may not be playing nice either.

I have observed some mitigating measures, though.

NB *VS Code didn't "design" test discovery; that is the job of the testing framework. Make sure you have a basic grasp on how it works.*

### Troubleshooting

For every "battery" of tests, VS Code will gladly tell you what went wrong, **right in the Test view panel**. To see this, expand the bar with the name of the project, and hover your mouse over the line that is revealed. *Look at the traceback*.

[image: Test Discovery Traceback]

**In the image above, the error is "No module named src". This is more interesting than it sounds. If I import a file from another file, that import path may not be visible to the test discovery mechanism. It may be running from a different "cwd". The best you can do is try to figure out the topmost path of your project, and either add or remove path qualifiers. Until it works.**

### Main causes

1. From time to time, VS Code will lose info on the project test configuration. Use **command** window (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>) to either:

   1. (re)scan tests
   2. (re)configure test spec for the project <-- important!
   3. restart Python Language Server
2. Python is supposed to remove the need for the empty `__init__.py`; it seems VS Code loves those. They should be in *each* folder that **leads to a test** folder. Not every folder, but the top-down path.

[image: "init.py" top-down hierarchy]

3. Depending on what you select as the "root test folder" in the test configuration, it might have different meaning based on what VS Code thinks is the *root* of your project. That probably goes for any specific folder too.
4. `import`. VS Code doesn't like syntax errors. *It is possible* some syntax errors will not get highlighted in the code.
   This (unfortunately) goes for *all the imports in your file*. But you shouldn't test invalid code anyway, right?

### Minor buggy behaviors

1. Running some other visible test might help refresh the discovery process.
2. VS Code *should* automatically (by setting) refresh tests on each *Save* operation. But it doesn't hurt to refresh it manually.

## TLDR

1. Look at the error items in the test panel
2. Re-configure project test discovery parameters from time to time
3. Make sure you don't have syntax errors (visible or not)
4. Create empty `__init__.py`s in each folder of your project that leads to the test folder
5. Clean up your import logic

P.S. The Test view has been extensively worked on and improved much over the course of 1 year. Expect changes in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing this since it worked for me.

`pytest --collect-only` helped me to show the import errors,
then run `pip install -e .` after

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I could solve it by deleting the cash folder  `.pytest_cache`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#possible-exit-codes it seems pytest itself is falling over do to some internal error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and tracked it down to my `pytest.ini` file.  Removing most of the `addopts` from that file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and struggle with it for hours. I think that there is a special resolution for every other platform configuration. My platform is:

- VSCode: 1.55.0 (Ubuntu)
- Pytest: 6.2.3
- MS Python extension (ms-python.python 2021.3.680753044)
- Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code (littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter - 0.6.7)

The worst thing has that the tool itself does not have a standard output (at least that I know of or could find easily on the internet).

In the end, the problem was

```
--no-cov
```

parameters that was not recognized by the VSCode testing explorer tool (that I copied from some page on the internet) and the error was showed by the extension *littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter* and it may help you to find where things are broken.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, same problem appeared each time when `flake8` linter reported errors. Even one error was enough to fail VS Code test discovery.
So the fix is either disable the linter or fix linter errors.
I use setup described [here](https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-01-setup).

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic way to get Django tests to run with **full** vscode support

1. Configure python tests

   1. Choose unittest
   2. Root Directory
   3. `test*.py`
2. Then each test case will need to look like the following:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class views(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        import django
        django.setup()

    def test_something(self,):
        from user.model import something
        ...
```

Any functions you want to import **have** to be imported inside the test case (like shown). The setUpClass runs before the test class is setup and will setup your django project. Once it's setup you can import functions inside the test methods. If you try to import models/views at the top of your script, it will raise an exception since django isn't setup. If you have any other preinitialization that needs to run for your django project to work, run it inside `setUpClass`. Pytest might work the same way, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

A one-stop solution for this problem is the `__init__.py` file. Place this file in your tests folder and the tests will automatically be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to pip install the a library, that was not installed.

I thought that it will give an error while running not error to show the test in the GUI.

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, VSCode is not able to find the needed dependencies it requires to run the tests and do the needed configuration.
This is happening because you have your tests configured to be ran inside a virtual environment, but VSCode has no clue about that.

To fix this, you need to instruct VSCode about the paths of your environment so it can do the detection based on that. Paste the following snippet into your `.vscode/settings.json` file.

```json
{
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "venv/bin/pytest",
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--no-cov"
    ],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "venv/bin/python"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I encountered this error, and was only able to resolve it when I noticed I had two venv folders floating around in my main folder (I had made a second one for testing some other installations). After I removed the second, unused venv folder, and refreshing the test tab, it found all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was pytestArgs in settings.json set to a specific subdirectory (subdir1) and not detecting others:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "subdir1"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

Solution is: either add the subdirs containing tests or empty pytestArgs and refresh

Answer (score 0):

For me my tests were setup for unittest framework, and there the tests have to be either in the top level folder or a single folder you specify.  The setting to automatically re-scan for new tests on save wants to run pytest.

pytest seems to be mandatory if you select the option to automatically re-scan for unit tests.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I crushed into a similar issue. First the tests are all shown under the test-icon.

This is my setup in settings.json, **not working**:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "--rootdir", "${workspaceFolder}/tests/tests_unit",
    "--html=${workspaceFolder}/build/test_report.html",
    "--cov-report", "term",
    "--cov-report", "html:${workspaceFolder}/build/coverage.html",
    "--cov-branch",
    "--cov=${workspaceFolder}"
],
```

My problem, and maybe yours too, lay in the line

```
 "--cov-report", "html:${workspaceFolder}/build/coverage.html",
```

The file or directory **coverage.html** is not found, when I click on the "Run all tests"-icon.

When I run the command-line

```
python -m pytest --html=./build/test_report.html --cov-report term --cov-report html:./build/coverage.html --cov-branch --cov=.
```

Everything works fine. However removing the stated line from the configuration leads to the tests to shown up again withing the "Test" view, but no html coverage report is generated.

What bothers me is that, the command line created a folder "coverage.html" below build-subdirectory and even when I copy the URL that is given as "not found"-error and paste it into explorer for example, the folder opens up.

So what is expected to be found by that line? A single file? Why is it not created by the run? The folder "assets" below build is created anyway, so it seems to work partly at least.