# Get Linenumber of TypeError causing test discovery to fail in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I have a python test file using the `unittest` framework and test discovery fails because of a `TypeError`.
Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to show the line number that causes this TypeError? It is really cumbersome to comment out tests to find the culprit

[image: IDE]

Comment: Probably not helpful, and you've probably already found it, but does any of this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837922/vscode-pytest-test-discovery-fails (I'm not a fan of IDE´s so I have no clue what might help, but thought i'd try to help in any way I can until some real pro's step in)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this worked flawlessly before and there was no new dependency added. I just added a few more tests. I just wonder if there is any way to get more helpful information from the test output where this TypeError is coming from.

Comment: Not sure, I don't think it's an IDE issue, it's probably has to do with the test library not fully printing the complete stack trace. Buf it you want, try running the code in a terminal instead of the IDE, see if that gives more debug data (haaardly doubt it tho). Is there a verbose mode in the test library?

Comment: Does pytest discovery work from the command-line when you run it manually (look in the Output panel and the Python channels to see the command the extension is running on your behalf)?

Comment: @BrettCannon yes executing the test script from IDE or via `pytest test.py` works but I do not see any discovered tests in visual studio code

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python with a reproducible sample so we can try to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @BrettCannon I saw that someone already opened one: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12043

Answer (score 1):

1.pytest works charmly with VS Code. More info is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing).

`pytest --tb=line`

[modifying-python-traceback-printing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing)

2.Or use pytest-instafail

```
pip install pytest-instafail
```

Sample code:

```
def print_failure(self, report):
    if self.config.option.tbstyle != "no":
        if self.config.option.tbstyle == "line":
            line = self._getcrashline(report)
            self.write_line(line)
        else:
            msg = self._getfailureheadline(report)
            # "when" was unset before pytest 4.2 for collection errors.
            when = getattr(report, "when", "collect")
            if when == "collect":
                msg = "ERROR collecting " + msg
            elif when == "setup":
                msg = "ERROR at setup of " + msg
            elif when == "teardown":
                msg = "ERROR at teardown of " + msg
            self.write_sep("_", msg)
            if not self.config.getvalue("usepdb"):
                self._outrep_summary(report)
```

[pytest_instafail](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-instafail/blob/b5b9cb372b68c20e8fa0b3cc670daf2236e255bc/pytest_instafail.py)