# VSCode Pytest discovery error but pytest --collect-only works

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, package, pytest

I'm trying to set up Pytest in VSCode to test a package I'm developing, and keep running into the error "pytest test discovery error". Running `pytest --collect-only` in the terminal successfully collects the file test_read_data.py, and debugging the test file shows no errors. There was an issue with imports (ModuleNotFoundError) but it was fixed by creating a conda env and installing the dependencies there.

My file tree looks like this, all contained in the project folder MY-PACKAGE:

```
.vscode
---> settings.json
docs
my-package
---> __init__.py
---> predict.py
tests
---> __init__.py
---> test_read_data.py
requirements.txt
setup.py
README.md
```

Both init files in the tree are empty. Predict.py contains a function read_data() which is tested by the test_read_data.py file.

My settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests","--no-cov","--rootdir","$MY-PACKAGE/tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.cwd": "$MY-PACKAGE/tests",
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
}
```

I've tried specifying the directory in `python.testing.pytestArgs` and `python.testing.cwd` as suggested in a similar StackOverflow question though the error didn't change. I was using Python 3.11 as the interpreter and have tried an earlier version, Python 3.7, to no avail. One issue I had earlier was the test file not running as I had `from .predict import read_data` which was fixed by changing to `import my-package`, however this installs the version on pip rather than the local one. Any suggestions? Happy to provide more info or code if needed.

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565473/18359438) solve your issue?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT thank you very much, that answer worked, I needed to specify the paths at the start of each test file before importing my package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the paths at the start of each test file before importing your package. You can do this by adding the following code at the beginning of each test file:

```py
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

This code adds the parent directory of the test file to the Python path, which allows you to import your package from the test file.

Make sure to replace `..` with the correct relative path to the parent directory of your package.