VSCode's testing framework breaks when referencing a file in a tertiary folder
I have a super simple test framework in VSCode as follows:
/.vscode
    launch.json
    settings.json
/python
    /resources
        some_data.tsv
    /src
        myapp.py
    /test
        test_config.py
        test_myapp.py
/venv

setting.json has:
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "."
    ],

(The following doesn't even work when unittestEnabled: true)
launch.json includes:
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/python",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}"
            }

myapp.py is one simple class/function to test:
import pandas as pd
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src')

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant = 42

    def get_constant(self):
        # pd.read_csv('../resources/some_data.tsv', sep='\t')  ## TODO: please get this working!
        return self.constant

test_myapp.py uses standard unittest framework to test that class:
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src')
from myapp import MyApp

class Test_MyApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main_program_loads(self):
        app = MyApp()
        print(app.get_constant)
        self.assertEqual(app.get_constant(), 42)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

In both these files I've added sys.path.insert(0, '../src') so the code/test can be run individually using the 'play' button in VSCode title-tab bar.
Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565473/2523501 I added test_config.py which got the test passing visually in Testing sidebar (they break without it):
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

main_folder = Path(__file__).parent.parent
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder))
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder / 'src'))
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder / 'test'))
sys.path.insert(0, str(main_folder / 'resources'))
os.chdir(main_folder)

No __init__.py's required.
However! As soon as I try and use some_data.tsv (i.e. uncomment line 10) the Testing UI framework shows failed tests despite the 'play' button on both myapp.py and test_myapp.py still working.
Error ends with:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../resources/some_data.tsv'

Isn't this a classic case that you're using a relative path without asserting the current working directory? Also, just to reduce the scope, it would help to run this without VS Code, does that work or does it fail as well?

I'm ultimately trying to test VSCode not the code itself. I can't seemingly get VSCode unittest to run what in PyCharm "just works" as soon as I declare "sources root" and "test root" to the relevant folders.

pathlib is a great library to work with relative and absolute paths. You can try for example to write your file myapp.py as follows:
import pandas as pd
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src')
from pathlib import Path

CURRENT_FPATH = Path(__file__).parent  # src


class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.constant = 42

    def get_constant(self):
        csv_path = CURRENT_FPATH.parent / "resources" / "data.csv"
        pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep="\t") 
        return self.constant

Note: in the directory tree, the csv file is located in resources/data.csv and in your code in resources/some_data.tsv.

I think, that his typo of data.tsv vs. data.csv is the main error here?

Ah yes, a simple copy typo in my post I've now corrected all to some_data.tsv (this wasn't the source of the error).

Thanks @matleg, your addition does make PyTest work in VSCode. But doesn't explain why the PyTest fail with my original read_csv() call given this exact structure does work just fine in PyCharm (with sources and test folders declared).

Just print the full path of your csv file before reading it in order to ckeck. As suggested by Ulrich in the comment, it is highly likely that the cwd is different in Pycharm VS VSCode, and that the relative path you indicated points somewhere else. Using pathlib and a relative fpath from the file, you can make sure this remains valid whatever the IDE.
