# VSC pytest tests not discovered and no error message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

After trying all solutions online (like [reinstalling python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988898/4091473), [checking if discovery works from the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57963397/4091473), adding or removing `__init__.py` files, deleting all `__pycache__` folders,...) VSC still doesn't discover any test and, what's worse, there is no error message or anything... simply silent failing. Pytest, from the command line, works as expected.

VSC runs the following command (which doesn't add any test or recognizes any in the UI):

```
conda run -n azureml_py38 --no-capture-output python ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.14.0/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.14.0/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear
```

When I run it in my terminal, I get:

```
>>>PYTHON-EXEC-OUTPUT

[{"rootid": ".", "root": "/mnt/batch/tasks/.../PROJECTFOLDER", "parents": [{"id": "./tests", "kind": "folder", "name": "tests", "parentid": ".", "relpath": "./tests"}, {"id": …

<<<PYTHON-EXEC-OUTPUT
```

so it looks as if the command is right and the tests can be discovered. My folder structure is simple:

```
 ├─.vscode/
 │    └─ settings.json
 ├─src/
 │  ├─ __init__.py
 │  └─ module_A/
 │       ├─ __init__.py
 │       └─ code.py
 └─tests/
    ├─ __init__.py
    └─ unit_tests/
         └─ test_code.py
```

My `settings.json` is basically:

```
 {
     "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
     "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
     "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
 }
```

and in my `.env` file there's only `PYTHONPATH=.`

My versions are:

1. vscode version: 1.71.2
2. pytest version: 7.1.0
3. python extension version: v2022.14.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Can [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-discovery) help?

Comment: Sadly no, I actually forgot to mention that I started with the docs and only the, when the problems started, I started googling and checking here.

Comment: Can project created following the documentation example be discovered by pytest?

Comment: Yep, it can be discovered as well as when I do it from the terminal. Somehow is VSC not properly configured or simply it doesn't find the tests. The only last ressource option I can think of, is reinstalling VSC...

Comment: After a long time, I found out that VSC cannot resolve simlinks. When the project is opened at it's absolute path, pytests finds out everything!